# Receive acknowledgement from TCP Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, iptv

I am Sending some Command to lg iptv. some command like:

```
Current temperature (Command: d n)
Checks the inside temperature.
Transmission
[d][n][ ][Set ID][ ][Data][Cr]
Data FF: Check the status
Acknowledgement
[n][ ][Set ID][ ][OK/NG][Data][x]
* Temperature is displayed as a hexadecimal value.
```

i am creating a tcp socket with this line of code:

```
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

and i connect and send some commands.
they are working fine but i cannot receive Ack with these lines of code:

```
data = data + "\r";
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
int bytesSent = user.Send(msg);
user.ReceiveTimeout = 2000;
int bytesReceived = user.Receive(bytes);
data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg, 0, bytesReceived);
```

i used this example of msdn and  again nothing received.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

is there any way to receive that ack?
i just can write client side and server side is in that tv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to receive ack.
because it is not exposed to the application level.
The TCP protocol will keep resending the packet until it receives a successful ACK.

Comment: so what can i do for it? i need to receive that ack to see for example tempreture.
when it receive a  successful ACK,what does it do with that ack?
@CodeJoy

Comment: The ACK is just to make sure the package is transferred properly. If you are not receiving anything. It may be caused by your firewall or Something is not right in your code

Comment: you mean there is no way?
I am working in a company. They had got this ack with VB.
what can i do in this situation, to receive temp @CodeJoy

Comment: Fire wall is off. 
my code is stick on:
     int bytesReceived = user.Receive(bytes);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124776/discussion-between-farshad-and-codejoy).

Comment: it needs special code for receiving ack. I mean there is a code that needs set-it equal to 0 and there is a code that needs set-it equal to 1 or 2 or ... and there is a code that not giving any ack! 
this was the answer. i found it with big help of @codeJoy. thank you so much